# Row computation on multiple columns

Tags: r

Is it possible in R to do this. I am struggling to do this.

For each Row, there are LC1,LC2 and so on....defined

```
Computation need to be done as follows for each row by row:

1. If F1=1, then SSN1=0, SSN2=0, SSN3=0 (If this condition is met then we should directly 
go to next row for computation, we dnt need to check for F2,F3)
     else  F1 not equal 1, then SSN1=SS1


If F1 was not equal 1 then we should proceed below
        Then it should check for if F2=1, then SSN2=0, SSN3=0 (If this condition is met then we should directly 
        go to next row for computation, we dnt need to check for F3)
            else F2 not equal 1 , then SSN2=SS2



If F2 was not equal 1 then we should proceed below
                Then it should check for if F3=1, then SSN3=0
                    else F3 not equal 1 , then SSN3=SS3
```

Input:

```
Item    LC1    SS1   F1    LC2   SS2  F2  LC3  SS3   F3
A123    MW1    20    1     SW1   10   2   RM1  10    2
A123    MW1    20    1     WK1   5    4   NA   NA    NA
B123    MW1    15    2     RS1   10   1   RM1  10    2
B123    MW1    15    2     RM1   10   2   RT1  5     1
```

Output:

```
Item    LC1    SS1   F1  SSN1   LC2   SS2  F2  SSN2  LC3  SS3   F3  SSN3
A123    MW1    20    1    0     SW1   10   7     0   RM1  10    2    0 
A123    MW1    20    1    0     WK1   5    4     0   NA   NA    NA   0
B123    MW1    15    2   15     RS1   10   1     0   M1   10    2    0
B123    MW1    15    2   15     RM1   10   2    10   RT1  5     1    0
```

Comment: Where exactly are you struggling? You didn't include any code in your question.

Comment: In order to figure out how should I proceed for this.

Comment: Looks like you need to use case_when in the dplyr package. Look into that and attempt the answer. If you can't figure it then update your question with what you have attempted. Also read the guides on how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have `dplyr` at the moment (failed upgrade :-( ), so here's a base-R brute-force implementation with nested `ifelse`:

```r
x <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, text="
Item    LC1    SS1   F1    LC2   SS2  F2  LC3  SS3   F3
A123    MW1    20    1     SW1   10   2   RM1  10    2
A123    MW1    20    1     WK1   5    4   NA   NA    NA
B123    MW1    15    2     RS1   10   1   RM1  10    2
B123    MW1    15    2     RM1   10   2   RT1  5     1")

x$SSN1 <- ifelse(x$F1 == 1L, 0, x$SS1)
x$SSN2 <- ifelse(x$F1 == 1L, 0,
                 ifelse(x$F2 == 1L, 0, x$SS2))
x$SSN3 <- ifelse(x$F1 == 1L, 0,
                 ifelse(x$F2 == 1L, 0,
                        ifelse(x$F3 == 1L, 0, x$SS3)))

x
#   Item LC1 SS1 F1 LC2 SS2 F2  LC3 SS3 F3 SSN1 SSN2 SSN3
# 1 A123 MW1  20  1 SW1  10  2  RM1  10  2    0    0    0
# 2 A123 MW1  20  1 WK1   5  4 <NA>  NA NA    0    0    0
# 3 B123 MW1  15  2 RS1  10  1  RM1  10  2   15    0    0
# 4 B123 MW1  15  2 RM1  10  2  RT1   5  1   15   10    0
```

There are several other ways to work it, most of them easier to read.

---

`data.table` implementation:

```r
library(data.table)
xDT <- copy(x)
setDT(xDT)

xDT[F1 == 1L, c("SSN1", "SSN2", "SSN3") := 0L ]
xDT[(is.na(SSN1)), SSN1 := SS1 ]
xDT[(F2 == 1L & is.na(SSN2)), SSN2 := 0L]
xDT[(is.na(SSN2)), SSN2 := SS2]
xDT[((F2 == 1L | F3 == 1L) & is.na(SSN3)), SSN3 := 0L]
xDT[(is.na(SSN3)), SSN3 := SS3]

xDT
#    Item LC1 SS1 F1 LC2 SS2 F2  LC3 SS3 F3 SSN1 SSN2 SSN3
# 1: A123 MW1  20  1 SW1  10  2  RM1  10  2    0    0    0
# 2: A123 MW1  20  1 WK1   5  4 <NA>  NA NA    0    0    0
# 3: B123 MW1  15  2 RS1  10  1  RM1  10  2   15    0    0
# 4: B123 MW1  15  2 RM1  10  2  RT1   5  1   15   10    0
```

(There's got to be a better way ... I can make it a little easier to read with `magrittr::%>%`, but sheesh ...)